# how do i make a console menu (c++) that i can return to after selecting something?

Tags: c++, menu, calculator

i made a simple menu and i know how to make choices and stuff but once i select a choice i don't know how to make it so that it returns to the selection menu.

```cpp
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "+====| LEO'S CALCULATOR |=========+\n\n";

    std::cout << "1 - Addition\n";

    std::cout << "2 - Subtraction\n";

    std::cout << "3 - Division\n";

    std::cout << "4 - circle area\n\n";

    std::cout << "+=================================+\n";

    int choice;

    std::cin >> choice;

    // CIRCLE RADIUS

    if (choice == 4)
    {

        std::cout << "what is the radius of your circle\n";
        double radius;
        double circleArea;
        const double pi = 3.14;
        std::cin >> radius;
        circleArea = pi * pow(radius, 2);
        std::cout << "the radius of your circle is: " << circleArea;
    }
}
```

I tried to look up what I was trying to do and i saw something regarding functions and being able to call them but i couldn't understand it. I tried to make the menu a function and in the choice i attempted to call said function but obviously it didn't work

im a beginner so if you have any other suggestions on what i should change id appreciate it and suggested resources for c++ are welcome

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72300849/how-to-make-a-loop-start-from-beginning-in-c/72301687#72301687) you can find a very similar question and an answer with a skeleton for doing it :) _(shameless self-answer reference :D)_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a loop (do while for example) and an option to exit the loop.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int choice;
    do
    {
        std::cout << "+====| LEO'S CALCULATOR |=========+\n\n";
        std::cout << "1 - Your menu...\n";
        std::cout << "5 - Quit\n\n";
        std::cout << "+=================================+\n";

        std::cin >> choice;

        // Your code.
    }
    while(choice != 5);
}
```